# How to turn a Tkinter window into a 'proffesional' application with taskbar and desktop shortcuts

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, windows-10

I was wondering if a Tkinter window could be a 'proper' application. By this I mean have a shortcut in the start menu, taskbar, and desktop in Window 10. If so, how could you do this? 
Note: I am using Python 3.7.3

I've looked everywhere online but can't find a up-to-date, proper answer.

Also, could the application be uploaded to a website for other people to download? In addition to this, is there any way to change the colour of the title bar (in the window, having a 'dark mode' option maybe)? I'm new to all if his, so I might just be missing something obvious, but I'd appreciate the help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is typically refered to as freezing / bundling / packaging a python application into a standalone executable (.exe on windows, etc). One third party tool that can do this for you is [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/), which supports the creation of standalone applications for various operating systems (Windows, Linux, Mac OS x, etc). Effectively this process takes all of your python application's dependencies (Python Interpreter, standard library, third party modules, external resources like icons, images, videos or sound files, etc) and bundles it together into a portable executable. However, there is a learning curve. As far as a "dark theme" is concerned, you'll have to implement that yourself in Tkinter.